# optional output function variable Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface, output

I have an `Input` function which have 2 options to Input by user, `GUI` and from `Command` In Matlab.
GUI is inputs by callback and in `Command`, simple in variable. What I want to build a function of it, but unable to create as `GUI` doesn't expect any output function variable and Command expects one variable, How I can create the function under my situation?

**My Code:**

```
function varargout = Input()

choice = questdlg(sprintf([ '1. GUI \n\n' '2. Command \n\n' ]), 'Input Choice?', 'GUI', 'Command', 'Command');
switch choice
    case 'GUI'
        GUI();
    case 'Command'

        [p] = Command;
        if nargout > 0
        varargout{1} = p;
        end
end
end
```

Comment: Why not use a custom output from it, like varargout{1} = []; or varargout{1} = 0; right below `GUI();` to indicate that GUI option was selected?

Comment: @Divakar I couldn't understand ur point well, please write answer so that I may have idea of ur point.

Comment: Something like this - `case 'GUI', GUI();varargout{1} = [];` and then `case 'Command' ....`

Comment: @Divakar When I call the function like `p=Input` its only works for `case 'Command'` but `GUI()` gives error of `p` thats the problem.

Comment: I tried it and worked fine for me.

Comment: @Divakar Oh thats cool, Please post answer of what U have tried.

Comment: I don't understand why I need to put all the code when I am  only inserting one line of `varargout{1} = [];` below `GUI();` and above `case 'Command'`. That's the only edit made to your code.

Comment: all right, I want answer so that this could be useful for others.

Comment: I thought it didn't work for you, but it did?

Comment: @Divakar I posted an answer here even if you came with the answer first. Since the post is 4 months old I thought it could be considered abandoned. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: @patrik Oh that's okay! Seems like ages ago. Hope OP accepts it, so it doesn't hang around as unanswered.

Comment: @ right! :) But better an unaccepted answer, than no answer at all I guess. But that is of ourse subjective

Answer (score 2):

That's right. Just put the lines `if nargout>0, varargout{1} = []; end` right after `GUI()`. That should ont be a problem. But, it would probably be good to have something like `varargout{1} = 0;` instead. This way you can make sure the function executes properly. Any other output or no output at all would mean that the function did not execute correctly.